# Firestore rules: placeholders for optional fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firestore rules allow you to enforce field types: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-fields#enforcing_field_types.
It also allows doing this for optional fields: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-fields#enforcing_types_for_optional_fields

So you could have something like:

```
function reviewFieldsAreValidTypes(docData) {
   return docData.get('variableA', {}) is map &&
        docData.get('variableB', {}) is map &&
        docData.get('variableC', '') is int &&
        docData.get('variableD', '') is bool &&
        docData.get('variableE', '') is string &&
        docData.get('variableF', []) is list;
}
```

I was wondering about the "placeholders" for the different data types in the above function. With placeholders, I mean the
`{}` for `map`,
`''` for `int`, `bool`, and `string`,
and `[]` for `list`.

Are these placeholders correct or should they always be `''` irrespective of the field type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rules.Map#get(key, default_value)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#get) returns:

> the `value` corresponding to the given `key`, or the default return value specified by `default_value` if no match to the given key is found.

So, you can use the following default values:

- `{}` which is an empty map
- `[]` which is an empty array
- `''` which is an empty string

Or any other default values for:

- `0` for an int
- `false` for boolean